# attempt to de reference null object in wrapper

Tags: visualforce

Whenever I click the save button, it always has an error of

```
Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page wrapperpage: Class.PTCSchedulerCX.save: line 151, column 1
```

which is this line:

```
objsched.p1.time__c = objsched.selectedTime;
```

`objsched.selectedTime` is null in the `save()` method but in `checkTeacherSched()` it has value.

could you help me help me fix my error? thank you

### controller

```
public with sharing class PTCSchedulerCX{

    public set<ID> teachers = new set<ID>();
    public set<ID> selectedTId = new set <ID>();
    public set<String> checkSchedTeaID = new set<String>();

    public List<Schedule__c> new_schedule = new List<Schedule__c>();  
    public set<string> qryTime= new set<string>();
    public string selectedSId                   {get;set;}

    public string teacherSet                    {get;set;}
    public List<WrapperClass> wrapTS            {get;set;}
    public List<schedule__c> wrapTeaSched       {get;set;}

    public List<String> saveItems               {get;set;}
    public SET<Id> myTea                        {get;set;}


    String day = '';
    public String getDay(){
        Datetime dt = System.now();
        day = dt.format('EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY');
        return day;
    }   

//GET STUDENTS//
    public List<selectOption> getsNames(){
        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
        options.add(new selectOption('--None--', '--Select Student--'));
        for(Parent__c p : [Select Id, Name, First_Name__c, (Select Id, First_Name__c, Name from Students__r) 
                           from Parent__c WHERE Name = 'Delgado']){
                               for(Student__c stud : p.Students__r){
                                   selectedSId = stud.Id;    
                                   options.add(new selectOption(stud.Id, stud.First_Name__c + ' ' + stud.Name));
                               }
                           }
        return options;    
    }

//MAIN CONSTRUCTOR//      
    public PTCSchedulerCX(){

        selectedSId = '--None--';
        selectedTId = new SET<ID>();
        wrapTS = new List<WrapperClass>();
        new_schedule = new List<schedule__c>();
        myTea = new SET<Id>();
        for(Schedule__c p : [Select Id, Name, Subject__c, Teacher__c, Time__c 
            from Schedule__c]){
                wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(p));
        }
        for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, room_assignment__c 
            from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
                wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
        }     
    }
//WRAPPER CLASS//        
    public class WrapperClass{
        public Teacher__c t1                         {get;set;}
        public Schedule__c p1                        {get;set;}
        public student__c s1                         {get;set;}

        public String strCheck                       {get;set;}
        public string selectedTime                   {get;set;}

        public WrapperClass(teacher__c myTea){     
            t1 = myTea;
        }
        public WrapperClass(Schedule__c p){
            p1 = p;
        }
        public WrapperClass(student__c s){
            s1 = s;
        }
    }

//GET TEACHERS//      
    public void fetchTeacherInfo(){

        myTea.clear();
        wrapTS.clear();
        wrapTS = new List<WrapperClass>();
         new_schedule = new List<schedule__c>();

            for (student__c stud : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c 
                from student__c WHERE Id = : selectedSId]){   
                    teacherSet = stud.teacher_set__c;
            }
            for (teacher__c myTeacher : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, middle_name__c 
                from teacher__c WHERE teacher_set__c = : teacherSet]){                  
                    myTea.add(myTeacher.id);
            }
            for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c,Subject__c , room_assignment__c 
                from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
                   wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
            }    
    }

//CHECK TEACHER SCHEDULE//  
    public void checkTeacherSched(){


            for(schedule__c objsched1 : [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c, teacher_cname__c 
                from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c =: myTea ]){
                    qryTime.add(objsched1.time__c);

            }

            for(WrapperClass objsched: wrapTS){

                if(qryTime.contains(objsched.selectedTime)){
                    objsched.strCheck ='Time is no longer available';
                }
                else if (objsched.selectedTime == null){
                    objsched.strCheck = '';
                }
                else{
                    objsched.strCheck = 'AVAILABLE';
                }

     }


    }

//SAVING RECORD//
    Public void save(){


        for (student__c stud : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c 
                from student__c WHERE Id = : selectedSId]){   
                    wrapTS.add(new wrapperClass(stud));
            }
        for (teacher__c myTeacher : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, middle_name__c 
                from teacher__c WHERE teacher_set__c = : teacherSet]){                  
                    myTea.add(myTeacher.id);
            }
        for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c,Subject__c , room_assignment__c 
                from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
                   wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
            }    

        for(WrapperClass objsched: wrapTS){ 

            objsched.p1.time__c = objsched.selectedTime;           
            objsched.p1.student__c = objsched.s1.id; 
            objsched.p1.teacher__c = objsched.t1.id; 
            objsched.p1.parent__c = objsched.s1.parent__c; 
            objsched.p1.subject__c = objsched.t1.subject__c; 
        }

        for(WrapperClass thisSched : wrapTS){ 
            schedule__c newSchedule = new schedule__c(); 
                newSchedule.time__c = thisSched.p1.time__c; 
                newSchedule.student__c = thisSched.p1.student__c; 
                newSchedule.teacher__c = thisSched.p1.teacher__c; 
                newSchedule.parent__c = thisSched.p1.parent__c; 
                newSchedule.subject__c = thisSched.p1.subject__c; 

                new_schedule.add(newSchedule); 

            } 
            INSERT new_Schedule; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly going on when you initialise your wrapper class and not getting into the details, the possibility of the line

```
objsched.p1.time__c = objsched.selectedTime;
```

throwing the error is if "**p1**" is not initialised (assuming you already initialised objsched).

so before assigning anything to variables of p1, you have to this

```
objsched.p1 = new schedule__c();
```

and then start assigning values to variables of p1

Comment: when i run, still that is the error but different line.
objsched.p1.student__c = objsched.s1.id;

Comment: @gelay, you'll have to initialize all of your object variables that you're tryin to access from the wrapper. Which are the following: Teacher__c t1, Schedule__c p1, and student__c s1.